# Почему метод «продолжает» работать после return?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

У меня есть .net core проект, есть экшен который защищен reCaptcha.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignUp(UserSignUpModel model)
{
        var recaptchaRes = await _reCaptchaService.Validate(Request, !Startup.IsDevelopment);

        if (!recaptchaRes.success)
        {
            return BadRequest("ReCaptcha is invalid");
        }

        await _userService.Signup(model); // Тут делается вызов userManager и отпрвляется email

        return Ok();
}
```

Для reCaptcha используюre CAPTCHA.AspNetCore (https://github.com/TimothyMeadows/reCAPTCHA.AspNetCore)

Форму отправляю через axios.

Суть в чём, на локальном хосте всё работает отлично, но в Azure проиходит следующее:
Отправляется запрос, приходит 400("ReCaptcha is invalid") и пользователь регистрируется. Я смотрел в хроме, отправляется только один запрос. Может у кого-то была подобная проблема? Может .net core как-то повторяет какие-то запросы в случаи неудачи... Может ещё что...

Comment: Вы уверены что условие if (!recaptchaRes.success) срабатывает? Может оно не срабатывает, вот и return не сработал.

Comment: Там есть отличие для продуктового и тестового кода: параметр `IStartup.IsDevelopment`. Возможно, если он равен `true`, метод `Validate` всегда считает капчу валидной, а в продуктовой версии нет.

Comment: А как у вас вообще этот метод компилируется? Если условие проверки не выполняется, то где возврат значения?

Comment: Ну код не из личного проекта, поэтому не могу всего показать. там есть return Ok() внизу(моё упущение).
В том-то и дело, что в продакшене и return BadRequest вызывается, и _userService.Signup(). Я не уверен, что они вызываются в рамках одного вызова экшена Signup, но успевают вызваться оба.

Comment: Вам стоит отредактировать код в вопросе, так чтобы он логически соответствовал коду вызывающему проблему.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать, что именно могло бы вас натолкнуть на идею?

Comment: Тут проблема в том, что в данном коде проблемы нет. Во всяком случае, если бы код действительно "продолжал" выполнение, то это стало бы серьёзной проблемой для всего .NET сообщества. Если и правда за один запрос одновременно срабатывают два метода, то значит проблема не в этом методе. Внимательней нужно пересмотреть весь остальной код - там где-то может оказаться ошибка. Ну или можете в этом месте поставить вывод в лог, что по-хорошему сразу нужно было бы сделать, и посмотреть, действительно два раза этот метод выполняется или нет.